# Can't recieve broadcasted message from laravel echo server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

In laravel-echo-console:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.5.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

[7:07:00 PM] - YSTAl2zDJP0HtuoCAAAA joined channel: public
[7:07:00 PM] - Sending auth request to: https://xxxxx/broadcasting/auth

[7:07:00 PM] - YSTAl2zDJP0HtuoCAAAA authenticated for: private-survey.2
[7:07:00 PM] - YSTAl2zDJP0HtuoCAAAA joined channel: private-survey.2


Channel: laravel_database_private-survey.2
Event: server.message
```

All looks fine, but I can't recieve this message in browser:

```
window.Echo.private('survey.2')
 .listen('.server.message', (e) => {
        console.log(e)  
});
e {events: {…}, name: "private-survey.2", socket: p, options: {…}, eventFormatter: t}
```

My event class:

```
   public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('survey.2');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'server.message';
    }
```

In laravel telescope I see:

```
{
  message: "wdfwsfwf",
  socket: null
}
```

does it normal that socket is null?
Also always 0 listeners for this event.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was here `Channel: laravel_database_ private-survey.2`
change this in `config/database.php`

echo must join to "`survey.2`" in this case

if `broadcasAs`

```
 public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'server.message';
    }
```

echo must listen "`.`server.message" - `dot` before says not using namespace - this is event - not channel!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28210
Commenting out the `'prefix'` line for redis in `config/database.php` should make the trick, although I'd avise to read the link further for more insight.

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
//            'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_',
        ],
```